# install apps on sd card

Tags: applications

My BLU Studio 5.5 won't allow me to install anymore apps. I have a 18G SD card installed. When accepting to install it says "Error downloading phone had insufficient space". What do I do to install more apps.?

Comment: Beside that: Where did you get an **18** GB card?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a partition on your SD that you can then mount to your phone storage.

Here is a tutorial about it.

http://www.skyneel.com/2013/10/Increase-internal-memory-in-Android-Mobiles-in-easy-steps.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer some of the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also in order to do this, they would need to [tag:root] the device. Requirement 4 is: "4. Your android phone **must be rooted**."